# Magento 2 - Check if shipping cost in cart is 0,00, then change it into text

Tags: magento2, shipping, knockoutjs

We would like to check in the checkout cart if the shipping cost is 0,00 and then replace it by text: "free".
Therefore I copied the file `/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html` to our theme and tried the following below.

Sadly that does not seem to work and it does not display any value, so it seems that it does not load the value as numbers I guess.

How can we check the shipping cost using the knockout code and then display text?

```
<!-- ko if: getValue() < 1.00 -->
<td class="amount">
    <span class="shipping-free"><!-- ko i18n: 'Free' --><!-- /ko --></span>
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: getValue() > 1.00 -->
<td class="amount">
    <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Try console logging in the `getValue` function to understand what format it's returning

Comment: Or you could maybe try doing `<!-- ko if: parseFloat(getValue()) < 1 -->`

Comment: @JayGhosh Thanks! That's what I also tried, but sadly that does not seem to work.

Comment: @JGeer let me know if given solution works for you. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulBarot Thanks! Just replied to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
    <!-- ko if: totals()['shipping_amount'] < 1.00 -->
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="shipping-free"><!-- ko i18n: 'Free' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: totals()['shipping_amount'] > 1.00 -->
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are working in wrong file

```
Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html
```

if you wanna change shipping rate title or text then add your code in below file in your theme

for cart

```
/app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html
```

for checkout

> `/app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html`

Comment: Thanks! But that is for the shipping calculation, I need it inside the cart summary.

Comment: then override /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shipping.html this file and add condition based on getValue() (getValue is shipping amount)

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem here. I want to check if the value is $ 0,00 and then replace it by text. That code will be placed also in that template file for the checkout.